# Jquery Guillotine Plugin - possible to zoom out beyond 'best fit'

Tags: jquery

using the Guillotine plugin here [Guillotine Plugin](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine/)

You can only zoom out as far as 'best fit' allows so if you have a square uploaded image in a letter box crop area you cannot zoom out to see the whole square..its sides have to reach to the edge of the letter box.

Is it possible to enable the plugin in to zoom out further, resulting in a negative zoom value, which would require your image processing in the background to add in white space.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There doesnt seem to be any options for allowing negative zooms so I poked around in the source code and you can change/comment out these lines to achieve this.

Doing so also 'breaks' the drag limits so the image will no longer snap to the edges of the crop area.

This is the offset function changes

```
    Guillotine.prototype._offset = function(left, top) {
  if (left || left === 0) {
    if (left < 0) {
      //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
      //left = 0;
    }
    if (left > this.width - 1) {
      //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
      //left = this.width - 1;
    }
    this.canvas.style.left = (-left * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
    this.left = left;
    this.data.x = Math.round(left * this.op.width);
  }
  if (top || top === 0) {
    if (top < 0) {
      //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
      //top = 0;
    }
    if (top > this.height - 1) {
      //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
      //top = this.height - 1;
    }
    this.canvas.style.top = (-top * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
    this.top = top;
    return this.data.y = Math.round(top * this.op.height);
  }
};
```

This is in the zoom function changes

```
//REPLACE BELOW LINE TO ALLOW NEGATIVE ZOOMS IE DONT BEST FIT
//if (w * factor > 1 && h * factor > 1) {
  if (w * factor > 0 && h * factor > 0) {
```